# How to set the JComboBox back to its default item

Tags: java, swing

I have 24 JComboBox consisting of numbers, 2 JButton for "COMPUTE" and "CLEAR ALL". my COMPUTE BUTTON works just fine. But for the CLEAR ALL button I cant get my desired outcome. I would like to have the clear JButton to act when clicked, by returning all JComboBox to its default number 0. Please help. What would be the best code for this.

Comment: Come on Carol, you know that you are supposed to show your code and especially your attempt to solve the problem first. For how else will we know what you're doing wrong? We've been through all this before with you, so we shouldn't have to be repeating ourselves.

Answer (score 3):

```
setSelectedItem(Integer.valueOf(0));
```

Give this in the event-handler of `CLEAR ALL` button.

Comment: I think @Carol may be using `Integer`, so `setSelectedItem(Integer.valueOf(0))`; `setSelectedIndex(0)` may be an alternative.

Comment: we can parse it back to integer when we use :P lol , kidding, accepted your suggestion as a better one!

Answer (score 0):

jcombobox.setSelectedIndex(0);
works fine than jcombobox.setSelectedItem(Integer.valueof(0); in different scenario